# Probability approximation of no collisions

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, birthday-attack

I am comparing the actual probability of no collisions to the probability approximation formula of no collisions from the Understanding Cryptography text.

The approximation is as follows:

$$P(\text{no collisions}) = \frac{e^{-t(t-1)}}{2 \cdot 2^n}$$

I know that t represents the number of elements but I am confused about the denominator. The text says that $n$ is the output width of $h()$. I don't really understand this. Does this mean that for lets say the Birthday Paradox, $n  = 365$? So the denominator would be $2 \cdot 2^{365}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a hash function with a 128 bit output, n=128. Such a function has $2^{128}$ possible outputs.

For the birthday paradox you have 365 different outputs, i.e. $2^n = 365$ or $n = \log_2 {365} \approx 8.5$.

You'll also find alternative versions of this formula, which omit the `2^` part in the formula: $\frac{e^{-t(t-1)}}{2 \cdot N}$. In that case you'd use $N=365$ for the birthday paradox and $N=2^{128}$ for the 128 bit hash.

If $t$ is small compared to $N=2^n$, the formula can be approximated as:

$$1-\frac{t(t-1)}{2}\frac{1}{
N}=1-\frac{1+2+3+...+(t-1)}{N}=1-(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{2}{N}+\frac{3}{N}+...+\frac{t-1}{N})$$

Which is intuitive, since the first value has no chance of collision, the second can collide with 1 existing value with probability $\frac{1}{N}$, the third can collide with 2 existing values with probability $\frac{2}{N}$, etc.

Comment: Ok, I see now. So then the denominator for the approximation would be 2 * 365 or 730.

Comment: @user822719 Yes. The factor 2 in the denominator comes from $1+2+3+ ... +(t-1)=\frac{t\cdot(t-1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The approximate formula as given in the question is "wrong". The "correct" approximation (i.e., better, but of same complexity of evaluation as that given) is
$$P(no~~collisions~~in~~t~~samples)=e^{\frac{-t(t-1)}{2N}}=e^{\frac{-t(t-1)}{2\cdot 2^n}}$$

Let $A_k$ be the event that no collision occurs in the $k^{th}$ sample. Then, assuming the samples of the hash function are independent and uniform in the hash function output space without replacement,
$$P(no~~collisions~~in~~t~~samples)=P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)\cdots P(A_k|A_{k-1})\cdots P(A_t|A_{t-1})$$
which becomes
$$
1 \times \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)\times \cdots \times\left(1-\frac{k-1}{N}\right)\times \cdots \times \left(1-\frac{t-1}{N}\right)$$
now using the approximation $1-x \leq e^{-x}$ for positive $x$ and adding the exponents inside the exponential gives the upper bound (which is very accurate since $N$ is huge)
$$P(no~~collisions~~in~~t~~samples)=\exp \left({\frac{-(1+2+\cdots+(t-1))}{2N}} \right)$$
and using the arithmetic series sum to replace $1+2+\cdots+(t-1)$ by $t(t-1)/2$ gives the formula I claim above.